# difference between someone was ill vs someone became ill

Tags: word-difference

I would like to know if there is any difference between these two sentences:

> My friend had drunk some contaminated water and she was ill.
>
> My friend had drunk some contaminated water and she became ill.

Comment: It would be wonderful to know what _you_ think is the difference between the two sentences. It is _so_ much easier for us to help you if we know what you have learned on your own. If you looked up the verb _become_ in an English dictionary, it would be very helpful if you could tell us what you found there.

Comment: Well, "**become ill**" is really awkward. I've never heard anyone say that. It's usually "**get ill**" or "**catch an illness**".

Comment: @SovereignSun - Really, you need to start doing a little research before you post such ill-informed comments. If you’ve never heard that expression before, [start](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#q=%22might+become+ill%22&start=90) [reading](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#q=%22can+become+ill%22&start=110)

Comment: Hello SovereignSun and J.R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

> My friend had drunk some contaminated water and she **was** ill.

we only know two facts, drinking contaminated water and being ill. We assume one led to the other, but it is not necessarily so (she may have already been ill).

But in:

> My friend had drunk some contaminated water and she **became** ill.

*became* indicates a change from one state to another. In this case, she was not ill, drank the water, and then was ill.

see [*become*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/become):

> 1. link verb
>      If someone or something becomes a particular thing, they start to change and develop into that thing, or start to develop the characteristics mentioned.